# Npm ERR! Missing Script: Start when deploying to heroku

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku

I do have a procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

here's my package.json:

```
{
"name": "easyrtc_server_example",
"version": "0.1.6",
"author": "Priologic Software Inc. info@priologic.com (http://priologic.com/)",
"description" : "Simple EasyRTC server example which includes EasyRTC, Express, and Socket.io",
"main":"server.js",
"private": true,

"scripts": { 
"start": "node server.js"
},

"dependencies" : {
"express": "^4.10.7",
"serve-static": "^1.8.0",
"socket.io": "^1.4.5",
"bcryptjs": "",
"body-parser": "",
"connect-flash": "",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
"express-handlebars": "",
"express-messages": "",
"express-session": "",
"express-validator": "",
"mongodb": "",
"mongoose": "",
"passport": "",
"passport-http": "",
"passport-local": ""
},

"license": "BSD2",

"engines": {
"node": ">=0.8"
}
}
```

Here's my npm-error log.

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli 'start' ]

2 info using npm@3.10.10

3 info using node@v6.10.2

4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start

4 verbose stack at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)

4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5

4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:356:5

4 verbose stack at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:320:45)

4 verbose stack at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:354:3)

4 verbose stack at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:124:5)

4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:243:12

4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16

4 verbose stack at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)

4 verbose stack at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)

5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Nette\Desktop\pektos_1

6 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600

7 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

8 error node v6.10.2

9 error npm v3.10.10

10 error missing script: start

11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:

11 error https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

help me guys please :(

Comment: can you give a git url with all the important files? (you don't have to put all the app, just so i can reproduce the bug)

Comment: what do you mean by this @Amine you mean i need to git pull? something like that

Comment: Can you git push to a github repository? I 'd just want to reproduce the bug with all the files and not just the logs

Comment: i don't really understand what you are saying . i'm really new to this kind of thing so please bare with me . how can i achieve that?

Comment: have you ever used git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's very late but if someone encounter this kind of problem like mine here's what i did on my procfile

```
worker: node server.js
```

thats what i did.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too simple but did you try to make a "Procfile" file instead of just "procfile" with an uppercase P

Comment: sorry i just wrote down procfile but in my project is Procfile

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this error was because i was in the incorrect folder, i had to up a level and ran again npm start and it worked